# Logout button just adding a new page on top of the current page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a profile page in my app , there a logout button once clicked on that i am displaying the login page.

my code is like this,

```
 FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        token = null;
                      });

                      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(CupertinoPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => LoginPage()

                      ));

                    },
                    child: Text(
                      Logout,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ),
```

but its just adding a login page on top of the current page. so if I dragged the screen from left to right its going back to the profile page how to fix this.

have a look on this

[image: this]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to completely clear the stack and not just replace the top of it.

You can do this way:

```
Navigator.of(context)
  .pushAndRemoveUntil(
    CupertinoPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => LoginPage()
    ),
  (_) => false,
);
```

The second argument is the condition which stops the popping when it returns true.

By making it return always false you'll pop the rest of the stack, keeping only the current route.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing knowledge. It worked as expected!

Comment: hi, it worked perfectly for the android, but for iOS it still  the same, is there any change needed for  iOS platform

Comment: Not that I know. Are you using CupertinoApp or MaterialApp?

Comment: hi, Its working now, I forgot to add the code where I am checking if the platform is iOS, thats why it was not working for the iOS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hy Harish,

to switch between the pages after logging in, i would use `provider`.

Step to step:

▶ Install Provider in your app `pubspec.yaml` file

```
dependencies:
  path_provider: ^3.1.0+1 // install the last version
```

for more info's about this package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-readme-tab-).

▶ Make a new dart file named up to you, as example logging_provider.dart, write in that some thing like this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoggingProvider with ChangeNotifier{

  final bool isLoggedin = false;

  LoggingProvider(this.isLoggedin);

  setRegistrationStatus(bool status){
    isLoggedin = status;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

▶ Add provider to your main class in the main.dart file:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider< LoggingProvider >(
          builder: (_) => LoggingProvider(true), // here you can give him a status before abb is complied
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Provider.of< LoggingProvider >(context).isLoggedin? // if isLoggedin setted as true show Home else show LoginPage
                                                        HomePage() : // as example
                                                        LoginPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

▶ Set the login status from your logout button like:

```
 FlatButton(
  onPressed: () => Provider.of<LoggingProvider>(context).setRegistrationStatus(false),
  ...
```

I hope I could help you with this mini examples of code.

Comment: Hi Khalil , Thank you for sharing , definitely I will go through that